# the problem with logout in php logout script

Tags: php

this is my logout script

```
<?php

session_start();
include "../config.php";
include "../header.php";
include "../style.php";

if( session_is_registered("alogin") ) {
session_unset();
session_destroy();
    ?> <p>You are logged out now. Click <a href=login.php>here</a> to log back in!</p> <?
  }
else  {
    ?> <p>You are already logged out. Click <a href=login.php>here</a> to login!</p> <?
    }

include "../footer.php";
?>
```

I logout from my admin panel  but when i try to login back it automatically go to my admin panel

Comment: Just to make it clear what's happening here - you click the login link, expecting it to show the login form, but instead it immediately redirects you as though you are still logged in?

Comment: Yes, your are right !

Comment: You successfully get the "You are logged out now." message?

Comment: ya....but I can direct login to my admin panel..without password...every can

Comment: Can you show the login code?